# Change the tick labels of a seaborn barplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm trying to create a `seaborn` bar plot with three stacked figures that share an x axis and I want the x axis tick labels to be the product name, rotated by 90 degrees so they're legible.

I have managed to do this with a single figure plot using the following code:

```
ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(15, 7), sharex=True)


#products_bar
products_bar = sns.barplot(x=products_all.index, y=products_all['Unique Purchases'], palette="tab10")

products_bar.set_xticklabels(products_all.index)

for item in products_bar.get_xticklabels():
   item.set_rotation(90)
```

However, when I try to repeat this with the three figure (which splits the same data into three filters), the labels stay stubbornly as numbers from the dataframe instead. Here is the code -

```
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(15, 10), sharex=True)

products_bar.set_xticklabels(organic.index)

for item in products_bar.get_xticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(45)

products_bar = sns.barplot(x=organic.index, y=organic['Unique Purchases'], palette="tab10", ax=ax1)
products_bar = sns.barplot(x=paid.index, y=paid['Unique Purchases'], palette="tab10", ax=ax2)
products_bar = sns.barplot(x=social.index, y=social['Unique Purchases'], palette="tab10", ax=ax3)
```

I'm not entirely sure what keywords to search to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you used `sharex=True`, you just change the axis ticks on the last plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

idx = ["day"+str(i) for i in range(5)]

organic = pd.DataFrame({"Unique Purchases":np.random.randint(1,10,5)},index=idx)
paid = pd.DataFrame({"Unique Purchases":np.random.randint(1,10,5)},index=idx)
social = pd.DataFrame({"Unique Purchases":np.random.randint(1,10,5)},index=idx)

f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(15, 10), sharex=True)

ax1 = sns.barplot(x=organic.index, y=organic['Unique Purchases'], palette="tab10", ax=ax1)
ax2 = sns.barplot(x=paid.index, y=paid['Unique Purchases'], palette="tab10", ax=ax2)
ax3 = sns.barplot(x=social.index, y=social['Unique Purchases'], palette="tab10", ax=ax3)

ax3.tick_params(labelrotation=45)
```

[image]